# PSexec on remote machine hangs running from Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, psexec

I'm running TeamCity version 7.1.4 with a step that  uses PSEXEC in order to run batch file on a remote machine. The batch file should extract files and deploy them.
Running the PSEXEC from command prompt completes the task.
Running from team city i always get the following hang:

> PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely [12:19:34]Copyright (C)
>
> 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich [12:19:34]Sysinternals -
>
> www.sysinternals.com

Comment: Check the user account that TeamCity is running as.  First time you run PsExec you get this 'do you accept the license agreement' - perhaps that's popped up for your service and it can't get past? Is it possible to log in interactively as the user that's running TeamCity and run PsExec the once to get past that?

Answer (score 12):

It hangs because PsExec shows a window to accept the End User Agreement.
I solved adding the

> -accepteula

switch to the command.
This flag suppresses the display of the license dialog.

Read [Using PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) for full command line parameters.