# Starting GUI programs via OpenSSH on Windows?

Tags: user-interface, ssh, automation, windows-10

I'm trying to execute a labview VI, launching that from a .bat file, called via ssh, from another Windows machine.
So I do

```
 ssh myuser@IP
 cd  Desktop
 launchVis.bat
```

I connect with user and password. myuser have all the rights to launch the batch file.
Meanwhile I check the execution via RDP connection on the same machine.

If I run the bat file from a cmd line on the remote machine, the VI starts normally
If I run the bat file from the ssh connection, i can see the output of echoes in the bat file but LabVIEW will be launched in a different session from RDP-TCP#1.
The result is that I can see a "LabVIEW" process started in a Session named Services, but I cannot see the VI executing and in general, I don't know IF is executing or not.

Googling about the problem, It seems that I cannot avoid to start processes in "Services" Session and, for this reason, I cannot launch any GUI Program via SSH.
Suggested solutions are using PsExec or, maybe a third part of ssh Server (with a third part ssh Server I reached my goal over Windows 7)

Comment: It seems that if you want to launch a GUI interface, you should launch sshd server as user and not as a Service. Unfortunately, if you try to launch it as a User, even with administrator privileges, it fails.

Answer (score 10):

Running SSHd as a service makes launching desktop applications difficult, because a service has no access to the user desktop (Windows Station, `WinSta0`) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278373/how-to-start-a-process-from-windows-service-into-currently-logged-in-users-sess)

**Option 1: Start SSHd as a user**

- This fails with the latest OpenSSH implementation with `fork of unprivileged child failed`, as running SSHd as a user is no more possible since OpenSSH 7.5 released in 2017 [link](https://serverfault.com/a/861842/192675)
- Use an old implementation or a fork of OpenSSH, e.g. dropbear, FreeSSH or similar

**Option 2: Use a launcher that has access to the Windows Station**

On Windows, there are 2 options left to launch desktop applications over SSH: [link to Github OpenSSH issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1676)

- schtasks
- psexec on localhost

Usage:

```
ssh user@host "psexec -i 1 mydesktoplauncher.bat"
```

See [psexec documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) for optional arguments like `-i 1`

Comment: Hi Domih - i tried the above psexec command but seems it just gets stuck - i am trying something very basic - 

C:\PSEXEC>ssh Administrator@xx.xxx.xxx.xx "psexec c:\windows\regedit.exe" PsExec v2.34 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2021 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com 


Should i expect regedit to open with this? Authentication is key based and works correctly without the psexec command Server has OpenSSH, any pointers?

Comment: You try to call a program which requires elevated privileges. I would assume, UAC asks for your administrator password if you call it directly using command line. My experience is within the user context and how to bring an application to the user desktop. 
You could try to invoke runas, but this is basically where the real ugly things begin..

Comment: @MonojeetNayak I was getting the same problem and this fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680721/847536

Answer (score 6):

The "solution", using a third party ssh server is this:

1. Uninstall the Optional Feature "OpenSSH Server" of Windows10
2. Download and install the third party ssh server. I used freeSSHd
3. DO NOT install this software AS AS SERVICE.
4. Set users allowed in the Settings of the software.
5. Put a link to the exe of this software in the shell::startup folder, so it will be run at startup.

In that way, the ssh server will be launched as user and CAN execute GUI programs.

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to achieve the same goal with the Windows official OpenSSH server, because it fail to be launched as User, but seems working only as a Service

Answer (score 0):

#### Preamble

What helped me solve this issue is learning that running sshd in "interactive mode" is equivalent to running sshd as a regular user (not root). It's not something I've had to ever do on Linux, but once defined this way it's easier to find help online.

There are three issues with running sshd as an unprivileged user:

1. Can't access ports below 1024.
2. Can't read ssh host keys (located in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_{ecdsa,ed25519,rsa,dsa}_key{,.pub}`
3. Can't write PID file to `ssh_host_ecdsa_key`

[source](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/run-sshd-as-non-root-user-without-sudo/)

#### Solution

1. Host keys

Open cmd prompt in `%userprofile%\.ssh`

```
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t dsa -f ./ssh_host_dsa_key
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -b 4096 -f ./ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ecdsa -f ./ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ed25519 -f ./ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

2. Sshd_config

Copy `%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config` to `%userprofile%\ssh`

```ini
Port <BETWEEN-1024-AND-65535>
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_ed25519_key
PidFile C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\sshd.pid
```

3. Open new port in firewall

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port <BETWEEN-1024-AND-65535>" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=<BETWEEN-1024-AND-65535>`

4. Startup batch script

Create `sshd-interactive-mode.bat` in the `Startup`* folder:

```
start "" C:\Users\user\bin\SilentCMD\SilentCMD.exe "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\sshd.exe" -f C:\Users\user\.ssh\sshd_config
```

[SilentCMD](https://github.com/stbrenner/SilentCMD/releases) spawns it as a background task. Download it and save to =%userprofile%\bin\SilentCMD=
`start ""` prevents cmd prompt from [lingering on the desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626301) after sshd exits

#### Notes

- I chose to keep everything in user's `.ssh` directory, but you may choose a separate directory.
- Startup folder: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`