# what is different between SSH into WSL and the "Ubuntu" terminal/native app?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

Win10, WSL2, Ubuntu vanilla install.  I have an SSH daemon listening within the WSL2 instance (on a high-numbered port, in case that's relevant).  I just noticed that after installing the VSCode/WSL remote extension, if I execute `code .` from within the Ubuntu terminal/app/native console (sorry I don't know what this is properly called) it downloads/installs an instance of the VSCode server and at least so far appears to run as I'd expect it to.

```
### launch the "Ubuntu" applet from the normal windows environment....
[lwobker:/dtop/scripts/jumpstamper]$ code .
Updating VS Code Server to version 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3)
Downloading:  66%
```

BUT - if I ssh into the WSL instance (as the same user) and again type `code .` then it knows nothing of which I speak, and I get the standard Ubuntu "uh, sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean" response:

```
### SSH into the WSL2 virtual machine...
[lwobker:/dtop/scripts/fun]$ code .

Command 'code' not found, did you mean:

  command 'node' from deb nodejs (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1)
  command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.1build1)
  command 'cdde' from deb cdde (0.3.1-1build1)
  command 'tcode' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2)
  command 'ode' from deb plotutils (2.6-10build1)
```

I would have thought (clearly wrongly) that the Ubuntu terminal brought up is the same login shell as the one I'd get using SSH to log into the same virtual machine... but... evidently not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to run into a couple of things here.

###### `PATH` differences

First, and what you are running into at the moment, is the difference in `$PATH`.  When you run WSL directly on the host in the terminal, it starts your shell in a fairly "unorthodox" way.  At least, it's quite different than if you were running on a normal Linux host.

"Normally", you'd see something like `login` called to authenticate your user.  `login` (and `ssh`) uses PAM, the Plugable Authentication Module system to define what happens during the authentication process.  One of the commonly configured modules is [pam_env](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html), which can change the environment.

You can see this defined in WSL/Ubuntu in `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.  Both include the line:

```
session    required     pam_env.so
```

You'll see in the man page that `pam_env` processes `/etc/environment`, and on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL, that's defined as:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

That's the `PATH` you should see when `ssh`'ing in to your WSL instance, plus any changes made in your shell startup files.

On the other hand, you may have noticed that WSL doesn't actually require a login when you launch it locally.  Since it's running at the same permissions as your Windows account, and you're already logged into Windows, there's really no point in additional authentication here.  This is true no matter what WSL user you use.

WSL launches your shell using `/init`, it's PID1 init process.  `/init` is responsible for setting up the tight Windows integration, including (among [other things](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328686/1165986)):

- Appending your Windows path to your WSL/Linux `PATH`
- Setting up the Interop files needed that allow you to start Windows `.exe`cutables under WSL/Linux.

In case it's not clear, this is why `code` isn't found when you login via `ssh`.  Since VSCode is a Windows executable, and in your *Windows* path, it's only there (by default) when that path is specifically added by `/init`.  It is *not* there in the `/etc/environment` `PATH` used by `sshd`.

###### Remote GUI's in Windows

But really, even adding it to the path won't help much here.

I'm not sure of your exact use-case for trying to run VSCode through SSH, but note that running *Windows* GUI applications through SSH is quite a bit different than X forwarding on Linux.  There's really not a one-to-one equivalent.

By default, even if you provide the full path of the Windows executable, it will not execute through SSH.  This is to be expected.  Even the Windows OpenSSH server has issues with this since it runs as a service, and services do not have GUI access.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59880794/11810933) for some more information there.

I'm not sure if there's a way to get the GUI to display on the remote host through WSL.  I think it's unlikely, and probably not worthwhile regardless.

The best scenario I could see would be to use Windows OpenSSH running as a normal user, as documented in that previous question.  Then, once logged into your Windows user, run `wsl` there.  Then, you *might* be able to launch a GUI client on the SSH host itself.

###### Remote VSCode

What you probably want to do is access your WSL instance through VSCode *remotely* in the first place.

There are at least three supported solutions for that:

- Remote Desktop Protocol

  Assuming you have Windows Pro or higher, you can easily access your host desktop, including WSL and VSCode, from any client that supports RDP.
- VSCode's "Remote - SSH" extension

  Installing the "Remote - SSH" extension, or the "Remote Development" extension pack, will allow you to directly open any SSH instance from within VSCode, including browsing the filesystem and debugging.  It works the same way that you've seen with WSL, where it sets up a server inside your Linux instance that it then communicates with over SSH.
- Run the Linux version of VSCode and forward it to the ssh client

  This is probably my least favorite option, just because the other two are much better, but you can always install the Linux version of VSCode into WSL/Ubuntu, SSH in remotely, and forward the X client to an X host running on the same machine as your SSH client.

  Of course, if the machine that you are SSH'ing from is a Windows host, you'll still need an X server.  On Windows 10, you'll need a third-party X server, but on Windows 11 you could use WSLg for this.

  And, of course, this solution isn't limited to VSCode.  Any Linux editor or IDE could be used in this way.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful and very well written.  I didn't actually NEED to launch code in this specific manner - I just noticed that the behavior was different.  I figured there were things along these lines that explained that specific difference among others, and you've done a very nice job writing it up.  ;-)

Comment: @ljwobker Glad it helped!  And yes, I assumed that it was more "curiosity" regarding the behavior, which is a great reason as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.4, this problem could be solved by  running `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe` through SSH. You can run `code` inside it; the GUI would be shown in Windows.

Comment: That's odd - I wouldn't expect this to work, but I'll try it out.  Are you `ssh`'ing in from a remote machine to Windows?  Or are you running `ssh` locally, and if so which `ssh`?  Thanks!

Comment: I tested and found this works for both ssh from remote server to wsl, or ssh from local wsl to wsl.